# Finding max of array using generic E[] array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm very new to generics, so sorry if the answer is obvious.

I have a function max that finds the maximum value in an array. I'm trying to use a generic array E[] so that any array of objects could be passed into it, but in trying to test it I've found that (unless I'm doing something very wrong) it's actually only taking E[] arrays...which the IDE keeps telling me I can't make.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Max {
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[] list) {

    E comp1 = null;

    for (E e : list) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            comp1 = list[0];
            if (comp1.compareTo(e) > 0) {
                comp1 = e;
            }
        }
    }
    return comp1;
}

public static <E> void main (String[] args) {
    Boat boat = new Boat(1,2);
    Soda pepsi = new Soda(1,2);
    Comparable<E>[] oa = new Comparable[100];
    Object[] boats = new Boat[20];
    Object[] objects = new Object[1];
    Object stuff = null;

    final E[] a = (E[]) Array.newInstance(1,1);
    E e1 = (E) boat;
    E e2 = (E) pepsi;
    E e3 = (E) stuff;
    
    E[] es = {e1,e2,e3};

    Comparable<E>[][] es = {oa};

    System.out.println((String) max(objects[0]));
    }
}
```

As you can see from the bottom main method, I've tried using objects, object arrays, and Comparable objects and arrays of said objects. max() rejects them all, insisting it gets E[] type only. It gives as part of this error: "reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that Object conforms to E[]." My goal here is to test the max() method with any array of Objects, but it seems that I misunderstand how generics work in the case of arrays. Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually:

- Your generic method should use generic types.
- Whatever is calling it should use concrete types.

Your max method had logic errors, but its use of generics was correct.

Since your main method was passing arrays to it, the main method should not have used generics.

```
public class Max {
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[] list) {
    
        E comp1 = list[0];
    
        for (E e : list) {
            if (comp1.compareTo(e) < 0) {
                comp1 = e;
            }
        }
        return comp1;
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[] words = {"Don't", "overcomplicate", "your", "generics"};
        Integer[] ints = {5, 14, 4, 8};
        
        System.out.println(max(words));
        System.out.println(max(ints));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I think I got off on the wrong train of thought from the beginning, and ended up overcomplicating it all in the process. Remembering that the point is to simply pass in a String array to be compared helps, and I also appreciate pointing out the logic errors I made. I'll try to solve those on my own first, and refer to your solution if I can't figure it out.

Comment: No problem at all. You got pretty far on your own and I'm sure you would have spotted the logic errors quickly once you were able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two different E versions here.
Each method defines their own version of E, and only the one in max extends Comparable. Making a main method generic doesn't make any sense anyway, as the input will always be a string array, so remove that, and test your main method with any array of an actually comparable type, e.g. String.

this should compile:

```
public class Max {
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[] list) {

        E comp1 = null;

        for  (E e : list) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                comp1 = list[0];
                if (comp1.compareTo(e) > 0) {
                    comp1 = e;
                }
            }
        }
        return comp1;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(max(args));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of how "E" is working in each method. It helps a lot to know that they're not the same thing (I suppose I should have realized that, given that I never made an instance variable E outside of either method), and should be treated differently.